# Please explain this regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have regex which reads:

```
@"<img\s*[^>]*>(?:\s*?</img>)?
```

Can someone please explain this part:  (?:\s*?)?

What is that?

Comment: have you tried downloading one of the free tools (like expresso 3.0) that explains regex's?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 9, accepted):

match but don't capture any number of whitespace followed by a close image tag, zero or one times:

```
(?: = match but don't capture

\s*? = any number of whitespace (not greedy)

</img> = close image tag

)? = zero or one times
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

`(?:\s*?)` selects any whitespace, if it exists, after the image tag. The `?:` at the beginning tells the regex engine to not capture that group (meaning it won't be returned in the matches array)

Answer (score 0):

non-capturing group of any number of whitespace characters, followed by a closing img tag

Answer (score 0):

The entire expression will capture any `<img>` tags that have corresponding `</img>` tags (but it won't capture the close tags). It doesn't capture the close tags because the `(?:)` syntax means "match but don't capture".

Some restrictions that are part of this regex:

1. The `\s*` in the opening tag is redundant because `[^>]*` will capture this too
2. Only whitespace is allowed between the opening and closing tags

Some examples:

- `<img>` will **not** match
- `<img></img>` will match, but only capture `<img>`
- `<img attr="123"></img>` will match, but only capture `<img attr="123">`
- `<imgabc></img>` will **not** match
- `<img>  </img>` will match, but only capture `<img>`
- `<img>ab</img>` will **not** match

I highly recommend the Regular Expression Designer available for free at [www.radsoftware.com.au](http://www.radsoftware.com.au) for testing regexs

Comment: wrong - the ? after the final group causes it not to be greedy, meaning things like <img> will match